# Name mangling in linux sparc so library

Tags: c, name-mangling, nm, c++filt

I ve got some sparc libraries and I want to have list of exporting function with real names. Using objdump or nm I get names like `__1cEnameIcopyType6MpnIASN1CTXT_rnLAsn1TObject_4_v_` or `__1cHsurname2t5B6M_v_` so that c++filt cannot demangle them. I have tryed every style my nm has - gnu, lucid, arm, hp, edg, gnu-v3, java, gnat - result is the same. Could you please help me?

Comment: What libraries are those? C, C++, other? They come from where?

Comment: It looks like those C++ names were generated by Sun's own compiler tools which are, regrettably, not covered by the list that c++filt approves of.

Answer (score 1):

[Oracle Solaris Studio](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solarisstudio/downloads/index.html) should have support in it's own version of c++filt for your code.